# Android Emulator Stability Issues with the Driver Version,Emulator Became Laggy

Tags: android, emulation

My android emulator became leggy with this dialog displaying every time i open emulator,where can i find the update ? What should i do ?

Alert showing issue with the graphics driver.
[image: Screen shot]

Comment: In my case helped reinstall of Android Studio with removing all user settings

Comment: i reinstalled SDK tools but it did not worked for me.@Borys

Answer (score 3):

I have checked first the Intel driver utility update but the drivers are already up to date.

Then i have just seen that it's due to the HAXM is not rendering with the GPU enabled device while i am starting the emulator from Android Studio. So, I just got this methods:

1. Open your **SDK Emulator** folder (e.g. C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator )
2. Open **Command Line** window here
3. Enter the: `emulator -list-avds` (to see a list of available emulators)
4. Enter the: `emulator -avd avd_name -gpu host` (for the forced-choice hardware gpu)

You will see a warning again, but just ignore it.The emulator will no longer slow down.